# error while trying to update

Tags: updates

I get the following errors when trying to update:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/kirillshkrogalev/ffmpeg-next/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/kirillshkrogalev/ffmpeg-next/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the download from server and make sure to use "Main Server".

System Settings > Software and Updates > Ubuntu Software > Change the download from to "Main Server"

Note, some server mirror doesn't always have the updated changes/add-ons so it is better to still use the Main Server.